# How to save docker command on Powershell using SET

Tags: powershell, docker, cmd, scripting, windows-scripting

i'm trying to save a docker command as a variable in powershell, and i want to call that variable in another docker command.

right now, i did "`SET c_list=(docker ps -aq)`" which will output me a bunch of ids

then i want to did:

```
For ($i=0; $i -lt $c_list.Length; $i++) {
    docker inspect $c_list >> log.txt
    }
```

but the problem is that windows is not running the docker ps -aq. it just cycles through docker, then ps, then -aq as if there individual strings

Comment: Why not set an alias instead? Are you needing to use this in a build script or something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why its necessary to put the command in a variable, but here's a more idiomatic way to write what you're looking for:

```
docker ps -aq | % { docker inspect $_ | Out-File "log.txt" -Append }
```

This gets your list of ids, and then for each of those ids (`%`) appends the output of docker inspect to log.txt.